# No Response from NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I have the following code, which should simply load a URL with post data, and then grab the HTML response from the server:

```
// Send log in request to server
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@", text_field_menu_username.text, text_field_menu_password.text];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/test.php"]]; // Example Only
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    // Handle response
    NSString *response_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Data 1: %@", response);
    NSLog(@"Data 2: %@", data);
    NSLog(@"Data 3: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"Data 4: %@", response_string);
}];
```

Here's the output from each of the `NSLog`'s:

```
Data 1: (null)
Data 2: (null)
Data 3: (null)
Data 4:
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: All the variables are nil?

Comment: I updated the question with the exact output from each of the `NSLog`'s

Comment: `%d` is the wrong conversion specifier to use for the `length` of an NSData; it's the wrong signedness and, on some architectures, the wrong size. You should be getting a warning about this; if you're not, you should turn that warning (“Typecheck calls to `printf`/`scanf`”) on.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized the `request` object before setting its parameters. It should be:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
```

Comment: Perfect. And for anyone looking at this in the future, the `response_string` variable was the one that contained the correct response.